# How to randomize usernames on python

Tags: python-3.x, bots

It's for mass accounts creation, need it ranomized for example -- dadu23j8d8a

I really don't know what I have to change at line 24 -- http://pastebin.com/1ZDy58PU

And the last line here -- http://pastebin.com/raw/uHrrHHU0
def get_random_name():
    return "{}{}{}".format(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name(), random.randint(1, 100))

What do I have to change there?

Tried to search up alot of stuff on google and haven't found yet, anyone could help ? thanks

Comment: Meant to say 'Randomized' but whathever

Comment: please put your (simplified) code directly in the question, not as links that not everyone can follow (url blockers)

Comment: done it..........

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, assuming you want 11 randomized digits and lowercase letters:

```
import string, random
def genRandName(characters, length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))


>>> characters = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
>>> genRandName(characters, 11)
'efk331xruwk'
>>> genRandName(characters, 11)
'3axebe35pgr'
>>> genRandName(characters, 11)
'pmt3ul9cw6o'
>>> genRandName(characters, 11)
'd2j2xwznuq0'
```